# Responsive Design - making container element act differently on different resolutions

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, media-queries, web-frontend

As a part of a home interview assignment, I was asked to build a responsive e-commerce mini website site based on a Figma design I got.

#### Here's the mockup:

| mobile | tablet | desktop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

#### My solution process:

Create a CSS file with media queries, and for the card container give a display of grid. On each resolution, change the elements' columns and raws they span, to copy the desired layout.

#### The problem:

On a tablet, they wish to show 3 products on each line and to make the product card look like the mobile single card. See image below
 [image]

The problem is I ordered the card to change based on the resolution, so I kind of need to find a way to tell the card to look like it looks on mobile.

I saw it is possible doing it with an experimental technology which is called "[container query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries#container-type_3)", meaning that the size of the container will decide the element CSS and not the screen size.

Another possibility from what I've read online is that SASS allows you to create a class and tell it to behave differently on different resolutions (create the media queries inside the class essentially).

#### My questions:

1. Which CSS library/pre-processor should I learn to use?
   SASS? Tailwind? Styled Components? (I'm not using React so I guess Styled Components isn't even relevant, isn't it?)
2. I know I can solve this with pure CSS, but I'm not sure how. How would you approach this task?
3. Can anyone please attach a fully responsive website example with up-to-date code which I can study from?

#### Here's the demo:

```css
@import url("https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css");

/* ------------------- Variables ------------------------ */

:root {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;

  /* btn background colors */
  --bg-dark-blue: #0b76e0;
  --bg-blue: #55a0ea;
  --bg-light-blue: #d5eaff;
  --bg-baby-blue: #88bdf1;

  --bg-orange: #ff5c00;
  --bg-dark-orange: #b04000;

  /* text colors */
  --text-semi-gray: #7b8997;
  --text-medium-gray: #9fa9b3;
  --text-bold-gray: #626e79;
  --text-heavy-gray: #2c384a;
  --text-xtra-bold-gray: #55626e;

  --text-red: #df0923;
  --text-blue: #0b76e0;
  --text-white: #ffffff;
}

* > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  margin-left: 11px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #f2f4f7;
}

main {
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
  background-color: #eeeff1;
  padding: 25px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--text-xtra-bold-gray);
  line-height: 24px;
}

/* ------------------- /Variables ------------------------ */

/* ------------------- Global Classes ------------------------ */

.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.bg-dark-blue {
  background-color: var(--bg-dark-blue);
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: var(--bg-blue);
}
.bg-light-blue {
  background-color: var(--bg-light-blue);
}
.text-gray {
  color: var(--text-xtra-bold-gray);
}
.text-semi-gray {
  color: var(--text-semi-gray);
}
.text-heavy-gray {
  color: var(--text-heavy-gray);
}
.text-medium-gray {
  color: var(--text-medium-gray);
}
.text-red {
  color: var(--text-red);
}
.text-blue {
  color: var(--text-blue);
}
.text-white {
  color: var(--text-white);
}

/* ------------------- /Global Classes ------------------------ */

/* ------------------- Product Ticket ------------------------ */
.card {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 140%;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 51px 114px rgba(199, 199, 199, 0.15),
    0px 15.375px 34.3677px rgba(199, 199, 199, 0.0895633),
    0px 6.38599px 14.2746px rgba(199, 199, 199, 0.0605927),
    0px 2.30969px 5.16283px rgba(199, 199, 199, 0.0352376);
  border-radius: 12px;
  position: relative;
  gap: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  margin: 45px auto;
}

.ribbon-underlay {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgb(26 35 126 / 20%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  height: 6.5px;
  top: 10px;
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.ribbon-underlay.best-choice-underlay {
  background-color: var(--bg-dark-orange);
}

.ribbon-underlay.best-value-underlay {
  background-color: var(--bg-baby-blue);
}

.ribbon-overlay {
  color: var(--text-white);
  content: "";
  width: 140px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -19px;
  left: -7px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgb(26 35 126 / 20%);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
}

.ribbon-overlay.best-choice-overlay {
  background-color: var(--bg-orange);
}

.ribbon-overlay.best-value-overlay {
  background-color: var(--bg-light-blue);
  color: var(--text-blue);
}

.ribbon-overlay .content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 8px;
}

.ribbon-overlay .content > * {
  align-self: center;
}

.product .product-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product .product-rating {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  max-width: 49px;
}

.product .product-rating .numeric-rating {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33.6px;
}

.product .product-rating .stars-rating {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product .product-rating .info {
  color: var(--text-medium-gray);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.product .product-rating .numeric-rating {
  color: var(--text-xtra-bold-gray);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.product .product-rating .stars-rating {
  color: var(--bg-dark-blue);
}

.product .product-title {
  color: var(--text-xtra-bold-gray);
}

.product .product-discount {
  background-color: var(--bg-blue);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  max-width: max-content;
}
.product .product-company {
  color: var(--text-bold-gray);
}
.product .product-view-deal {
  background-color: var(--bg-dark-blue);
  color: var(--text-white);
}
.product .product-vendor {
  color: var(--text-xtra-bold-gray);
}
.product .product-show-more {
  color: var(--text-xtra-bold-gray);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.product .product-info .highlights .title {
  color: var(--text-xtra-bold-gray);
  margin: 10px 0 8px 0;
}

.product .product-info .highlights ul li {
  color: var(--text-semi-gray);
  text-decoration: dotted;
}
.product .product-info .product-price {
}
.product .product-info .product-price .current {
  color: var(--text-heavy-gray);
}
.product .product-info .product-price .original {
  color: var(--text-medium-gray);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.product .product-info .product-price .discount {
  color: var(--text-red);
}

.product .product-info .vendor-container {
  /*   display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; */
}

.product .product-info .vendor-container > * {
  /* flex: 1 1 100%; */
}

.product .product-info .vendor-container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.product .product-info .vendor-container .view-btn {
  border: 1px solid var(--bg-dark-blue);
  color: var(--bg-dark-blue);
}
/* ------------------- /Product Ticket ------------------------ */
/* ------------------- Media Query ------------------------ */

/* Media Query for Mobile Devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .card {
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(10px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, minmax(min-content, max-content));
  }

  .product .product-image {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column-span: 3;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 22px;
  }

  .product .product-image img {
    width: 160px;
  }

  .product .product-rating {
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
    grid-row: 1;
    align-self: end;
    bottom: 10px;
  }

  .product .product-rating .info > * {
    font-size: 8.96px;
  }

  .product .product-rating .numeric-rating {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .product .product-rating .stars-rating > * {
    font-size: 8.1px;
  }

  .product .product-discount {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .product .product-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 19.6px;
    grid-row: 4;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
  }

  .product .product-discount {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }

  .product .product-company {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    grid-row: 2;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .product .product-view-deal {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 4px 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 15px 0 10px;
    grid-row: 5;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
  }

  .product .product-vendor {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    grid-row: 6;
    grid-column: 1/3;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .product .product-show-more {
    justify-content: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: right;
    grid-row: 6;
    grid-column: 3/5;
  }
  .product .product-info {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(min-content, max-content));
    gap: 10px;
  }
  .product .product-info .highlights {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
  }
  .product .product-info .highlights .title {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 10px 0 8px 0;
  }
  .product .product-info .highlights ul {
    line-height: 16.8px;
  }
  .product .product-info .highlights ul li {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .product .product-info .product-price {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .product .product-info .product-price .current {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price .original {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price .discount {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container img {
    align-self: center;
    width: 65.83px;
    grid-column: 1/3;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container .view-btn {
    width: 152px;
    height: 32px;
    grid-column: 3/5;
  }
}

/* Media Query for low resolution  Tablets, Ipads */
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    column-gap: 15px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr max-content max-content;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(min-content, max-content));
  }

  .hide-discount {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .ribbon-overlay {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600px;
  }

  .product .product-image {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1/5;
  }

  .product .product-rating {
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 1/5;
  }

  .product .product-rating .info > * {
    font-size: 9.05px;
  }

  .product .product-rating .numeric-rating {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .product .product-rating .stars-rating > * {
    font-size: 8.19px;
  }

  .product .product-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 19.6px;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .product .product-discount {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 3/4;
  }

  .product .product-company {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
  }

  .product .product-view-deal {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 4px 40px;
    min-width: 170px;
    min-height: 36px;
    grid-row: 2/4;
    align-self: center;
  }

  .product .product-vendor {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 4/5;
  }
  .product .product-show-more {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 4/5;
  }
  .product .product-info {
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 4fr 1fr;
    row-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 20px;
  }

  .product .product-info .highlights {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/3;
  }
  .product .product-info .highlights ul li {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .product .product-info .product-price {
    align-self: end;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    row-gap: 5px;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 1/2;
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price .current {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price .original {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price .discount {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container {
    align-self: end;
    display: flex;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    gap: 15px;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container img {
    min-width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    flex: 3 3;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container .view-btn {
    flex: 5 5;
    width: 94px;
    height: 36px;
  }
  /* ------------------- Related Deals ------------------------ */
  .related-deals {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  }

  .col-md-4 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  }
  /* ------------------ /Related Deals ------------------------ */
}

/* Media Query for Tablets Ipads portrait mode */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    display: grid;
    padding: 20px 15px 10px;
    column-gap: 15px;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr 2fr max-content max-content;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(min-content, max-content));
  }

  .product .product-image {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1/5;
  }

  .product .product-rating {
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 1/5;
    max-width: 75px;
  }
  .product .product-rating .info > * {
    font-size: 12.25px;
  }

  .product .product-rating .numeric-rating {
    font-size: 32.8165px;
  }

  .product .product-rating .stars-rating > * {
    font-size: 11.08px;
  }

  .product .product-title {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 22.4px;
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;
  }

  .product .product-discount {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 3/4;
  }

  .product .product-company {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 2/3;
  }

  .product .product-view-deal {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 80px;
    min-width: 170px;
    min-height: 36px;
    grid-row: 2/4;
    grid-column: 5/6;
    align-self: center;
  }

  .product .product-vendor {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;

    grid-column: 5/6;
    grid-row: 4/5;
    justify-content: start;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .product .product-show-more {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    grid-column: 5/6;
    grid-row: 4/5;
    justify-content: end;
  }
  .product .product-info {
    grid-column: 2/-1;
    grid-row: 5/6;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 4fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .product .product-info .highlights {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    grid-column: 1/3;
    grid-row: 1/3;
  }
  .product .product-info .highlights ul li {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price {
    align-self: end;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 12px;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 1/3;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price .current {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price .original {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .product .product-info .product-price .discount {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container {
    align-self: end;
    grid-column: 4/5;
    grid-row: 1/3;
    gap: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container img {
    max-width: 65px;
  }
  .product .product-info .vendor-container .view-btn {
    width: 246px;
    height: 44px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}

/* ------------------- /Media Query ------------------------ */
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script defer src="./index.js"></script>

    <main>
      <div class="product card">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <div class="ribbon-overlay best-choice-overlay">
            <div class="content">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-trophy"></i>
              <span>Best Choice</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ribbon-underlay best-choice-underlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-image">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/916NVBBT0mS.__AC_SY300_SX300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product-rating">
          <div class="info">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> info </span>
          </div>
          <div class="numeric-rating">9.8</div>
          <div class="stars-rating">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> star </span>
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> star </span>
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> star </span>
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> star </span>
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> star_half </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-title">
          Sony X95J 85 Inch TV: BRAVIA XR Full Array LED 4K Ultra HD Smart
          Google TV
        </div>
        <div class="product-discount">50% OFF</div>
        <div class="product-company">SONY</div>
        <button class="product-view-deal btn">View Deal</button>
        <div class="product-vendor">On Amazon</div>
        <div class="product-show-more">
          Show more
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined expand_more">
            expand_more
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-info hidden">
          <div class="highlights">
            <h3 class="title">Main Hightlights</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>
                4K Ultra HD (2160p resolution): Enjoy breathtaking 4K movies and
                TV shows at 4 times the resolution of Full HD, and upscale your
                current content to Ultra HD-level picture quality.
              </li>
              <li>
                Voice remote with Alexa: Use the sound of your voice to do
                everything a regular remote would do: Switch streaming services,
                inputs, channels and much more.
              </li>
              <li>
                Access thousands of shows with Fire TV - Watch over 1 million
                streaming movies and TV episodes with access to thousands of
                channels, apps and Alexa skills, including Apple TV+, Disney+,
                Hulu, Netflix, Prime Video, Sling TV, YouTube and other services
                right from this TV.
              </li>
              <li>
                Hands-free control: Pair with your Amazon Echo and go
                hands-free, controlling volume, search, channels and more.
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="product-price">
            <div class="current">$99.00</div>
            <div class="original">$199.00</div>
            <div class="discount">(26% off)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="vendor-container">
            <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/amazon/amazon_PNG24.png" />
            <button class="view-btn btn">View</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="related-deals">
        <h2>Related Deals You Might Like For Tv</h2>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ead62a3458.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So **the problem** was that my *Card* class was changing as I ordered it according to the screen resolution, but I wanted it to change according to the Card container resolution so that on a tablet, I can spread 3 small (mobile layout) cards. I know I could have created a new class and named it *small-card*, but I wanted to give the same class name for all cards.

The **solution** for using the same class but changing its CSS properties without duplicating the same properties to a new class **was to use SASS**.

SASS has many capabilities, one of them is called *[mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)* -

> Mixins allow you to define styles that **can be re-used** throughout your stylesheet. They make it easy to avoid using non-semantic classes like *.float-left*, and to distribute collections of styles in libraries.

Also, one of SASS's great capabilities is to allow you to put the media queries inside the class, which allowed me to keep my *card* class well-organized.

Here's the improved code, written with SASS:

```
@mixin small-card() {
    // ...
}
@mixin medium-card() {
    // ...
}
@mixin large-card() {
    // ...
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .card {
    @include small-card();
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    @include medium-card();
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    @include large-card();
  }
}

.related-deals {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

 .card {
    @include small-card();
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SASS @mixin for that simple thing is just making your code harder to read and much longer overall. You can achieve same thing without @mixin

Your code with @mixin:

```
@mixin small-card() {
    // ...
}
@mixin medium-card() {
    // ...
}
@mixin large-card() {
    // ...
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .card {
    @include small-card();
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    @include medium-card();
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    @include large-card();
  }
}

.related-deals {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

 .card {
    @include small-card();
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Same thing without @mixin:

```
.related-deals {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

 .card {
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
    // small card CSS
    }
    @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    // medium card CSS
    }
    @media @media (min-width: 768px) {
    // large card CSS
    }
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

I would also probably change @media queries for something like this:

```
.related-deals {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

 .card {
    // small card CSS
    display: grid;
    @media (min-width: 481px) {
    // medium card CSS
    // change only what you need to change, don't need to duplicate small card styles
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    // large card CSS
    // again, change only what you need
    }
  }
}
```

So for example, now if you want to set `display: grid;` you have to do it once, for small card, and it will work for other sizes too. Change it only for other size if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

### Question #**1**

> Which CSS library/pre-processor should I learn to use? SASS? Tailwind?
> Styled Components? (I'm not using React so I guess Styled Components
> isn't even relevant, isn't it?)

I would recommend SASS but specificly using `.scss` files extension (`.scss` and `.sass` differs only in syntax, `.scss` is like regular css). Why? Because you can still write regular CSS but now you have more options and quality of life improvements. You can learn just one new thing and you will be fine if you don't know everything about SASS at the moment.

### Question #**2**

> I know I can solve this with pure CSS, but I'm not sure how. How would you approach this task?

**According to problem:** to make 3 columns with mobile like items/products:

Use grid container setting it with `@media query` for sizes you need and just leave single product style as it is on mobile view.

HTML:

```
<div class="products-container">
    <div class="product card"> [... content ...] </div>
    <div class="product card"> [... content ...] </div>
    <div class="product card"> [... content ...] </div>
    <div class="product card"> [... content ...] </div>
    <div class="product card"> [... content ...] </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .products-container{
        display: grid;
        gap: 1em;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}
```

Removed CSS:

```
/* Media Query for low resolution  Tablets, Ipads */
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.card {
    /* Remove this display: grid;*/
    display: grid;
    /**/
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    column-gap: 15px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr max-content max-content;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, minmax(min-content, max-content));
 }
 ...
```

This is your code after adding container with my css/html changes, copied product few times to have example, and removed display grid on `481px to 768px` query for .card.

[image: Your code with my edit]

### Question #**3**

> Can anyone please attach a fully responsive website example with up-to-date code which I can study from?

[zdrowepalenie.pl](https://zdrowepalenie.pl/)

This is my website made with SCSS, using Wordpress and Woocommerce. I can't show you source code, but you can inspect HTML and CSS code with browser.

I think it is preety good example for you. It is also not too complicated.

Comment: Thanks you @Dawid Frankiewicz. I accept your first answer to question number one, although not for question number two. 

I am now working on a solution with SCSS. I was looking for a way to avoid giving the card different classes, but I can't find any other option. So what I'm going to do, instead of just "card" and depending on the screen resolution to switch between "small-card" and "medium-card" etc.

Comment: @EstheticNerd I have just added container to make use of `display: grid;`. It is simplest way i know to do this, it is perfect solution for products display. Current solution is fine, although your code looks too complicated (grids where you could make it much simpler), but it works. It is correct approach for this problem. One product element, you only change styles for diffrent screen sizes

Comment: I don't disagree with using a grid. As a matter of fact, I am using it. I'm afraid you misunderstood my problem. See my solution above. I managed to avoid code duplications by using SASS mixins for the same 'card' class.